# uso de <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>

Tags: java, spring-boot

He intentado usar esta dependencia por aquello de que usa programacion funcional. pero me encuntro que todo lso import de la interfaz que tenia creada petan.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.w2m</groupId>
    <artifactId>W2M-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>W2M-1</name>
    <description>Preuba tecnica</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springdoc>2.3.0</springdoc>
        <auth0>4.4.0</auth0>
        <openapitools>7.2.0</openapitools>
        <lombok>1.18.30</lombok>
        <projectlombok>0.2.0</projectlombok>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${auth0}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapitools}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>src/main/resources/openapi.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>true</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <documentationProvider>springdoc</documentationProvider>
                                <modelPackage> com.w2m.aplicacion.dto</modelPackage>
                                <apiPackage>com.w2m.presentacion.api</apiPackage>
                                <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <annotationLibrary>swagger2</annotationLibrary>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                    @lombok.NoArgsConstructor
                                    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
                                    @lombok.Builder
                                </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${projectlombok}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
mi pom y la interfaz

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.Mapping;
import com.w2m.aplicacion.dto.SkillDTO;
import com.w2m.aplicacion.dto.SkillDTOEntrace;
import com.w2m.aplicacion.dto.SuperHeroDTO;
import com.w2m.aplicacion.dto.SuperHeroDTOEntrance;
import com.w2m.infrastructure.entity.Skill;
import com.w2m.infrastructure.entity.SuperHero;

/**
 * Carlos Diaz https://github.com/carlos033?tab=repositories
 */
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SuperHeroMapper{
    SuperHeroDTO convertToDTO(SuperHero entidad);

    SuperHero convertToEntity(SuperHeroDTO dTOS);

    @Mapping(target = "idSuperhero", ignore = true)
    SuperHero convertToEntraceEntity(SuperHeroDTOEntrance dTOS);

    @Mapping(target = "superHeroList", source = "superHeroesList")
    SkillDTO convertToDTOSkill(Skill entidad);

    @Mapping(target = "superHeroesList", ignore = true)
    Skill convertToEntitySkill(SkillDTO dto);

    @Mapping(target = "skillId", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "superHeroesList", ignore = true)
    Skill convertToEntityEntraceSkill(SkillDTOEntrace dTOS);
}
```

cual es el error ? xq no acepta los import?

Comment: ¿Puede ser porque estés intentando usar mapstruct-jdk8 cuando la versión de java que estableces es la 17? ¿Cuál es el error que te da? ¿Qué significa eso de que no acepta los imports?

Comment: los import no los acepta. entiendo que si vale para jdk 8 vale para 17 digo yo

Comment: Ah, que han puesto "-jdk8" pero vale para todas las versiones, que raro. ¿Y has probado a quitar "-jdk8" del artifactId? Yo lo tengo sin ese trozo y con java 17 y funciona estupendamente.

Comment: claro sin el -jdk8 es otra dependecia (la normal) es si rula. pero si ves como crea lso for ylas cosas usa jdk 7 no usa programacion funcional y se me ocurrio probar esta dependencia